# vertical align middle li with images

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/fzbhao5v/

```
<li>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff" /><span>Name</span>
</li>
```

I can do position relative and negative top to adjust the span up but the problem is I want the image to be responsive, so the relative solution doesn't really work in my case.

How to ensure my `span` within the `li` always be at the middle?

Answer (score 6):

You need to align the img as well, otherwise the browser won't know what to align the span *to*.

```
img, span {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/fzbhao5v/3/).